# How do I select columns including colspans in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

Assume I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I select all the cells in the fourth column, including the td[colspan="2"] that spans to it with CSS?

Comment: What do you mean "select all the cells"? Are you trying to style those cells the same?

Comment: @BrianBennett Yes, sorry, I edited the question :)

Comment: Not sure you can do this with CSS as you would be trying to select multiple attributes (http://jsfiddle.net/qwvxzjkv/2/)

Comment: Yeah, this one is tough because the table columns index differently. http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/pGnxH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not pretty but can be done with multiple selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/r4atjtfx/1/

```
tr:first-child td:nth-child(4),
tr:first-child + tr td[colspan="2"] ~ td[colspan="2"],
tr:last-child td:nth-child(3) {
    color: orange;
}
```

But to answer your question no selector exists to target different table columns.

Comment: Nice aproach but I think is too specific for each case... not a general solution.

Comment: @Danko: Exactly, which is why I edited because I now realize OP was looking for a specific selector to target different table columns (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Yep but still the best he can do with CSS +1

Answer (score 2):

It has been awhile, but I was searching for this and came up with a better solution.  A table can have multiple `<tbody>` elements and you can add a class to treat them differently.

```
<table>
  <tbody class="first">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="second">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="third">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then use `nth-child` selectors tailored to each `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child to target elements in combination that with not and attr.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/vL4t871x/)

```
tr>td:not([colspan])+td:nth-child(4):not([colspan]) {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
tr>td[colspan]:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
tr>td[colspan]:nth-child(2)+td {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrwst1b1/3/)

```
tr :nth-child(4), tr td[colspan="2"] {
    color: red;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### jQuery:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrwst1b1/)

```
for (i = 1; i < document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length * 2; i++) {
    console.log($('table :nth-child(' + i +') :nth-child(4)').html());
    console.log($('table :nth-child(' + i + ') td[colspan="2"]').html());
}
```