# how to use pure CSS to manipulate HTML table with only td elements, without editing HTML

Tags: css

I am managing a page on a site that uses a CMS. There are many restrictions - no jquery, javascript. Just CSS and HTML. Even some CSS is not allowed.

This site creates a report in HTML format from swims that meet a certain standard and the report overwrites the HTML on the page after every swim meet. I don't want to bother editing the HTML - too time consuming for every swim meet - not worth it. I want to edit the CSS so the HTML is displayed properly on different devices. Desktop and Mobile.

Here is an example of the structure of the HTML that is created by the reporting function.

```
<table style="border-width:1px; border-collapse:collapse" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Time</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Athlete</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Age<br />
        at Meet</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
        <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="topTdStyle" colspan="7"><b>Female 50 Free</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="topTdStyle">1</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">29.18L</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">CHMP</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">F</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">Lastname, Firstname</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">13</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">05/01/2021</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">Big Meet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="topTdStyle">2</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">30.11L</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">CHMP</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">F</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">Lastname, Firstname</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">12</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">05/01/2021</td>
        <td class="topTdStyle">Big Meet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> ...
```

The only difference between what should be a header element and what the other data is `colspan="7"` and the fact that there is only one line instead of 8 lines surrounded by table row element.

What happens when I use the following is that the label `Event` appears as the first table data element for the header - which is appropriate, but every `td` element in first position since they are all `td` elements.

I can't hide the `nth` of `td` because there are different numbers of records for each event. sometimes 1 sometimes 5, etc...

Would there be a way to only show "Event" for the table rows that only have one data element?

I don't know why the report adds a class="topTdStyle". It doesn't appear to be used anywhere and it's not in the CSS stylesheet

[Copy and Pasted CSS](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/):

```
*{ 
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops
note: the default HTML contains class="topTdStyle" which may be useful.
*/

table { 
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px outset #fff;
  text-align: left; 
  white-space: nowrap; /*creates scrollbar on iPads */
}
/*tr { border: 0px outset #fff; }*/

div, table, tbody {
    border: none !important;
}

/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
   /* tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
        background: #f2f2f2; }*/

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
    
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
        tr:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
    
    tr { 
        border: 1px outset #fff;
    }
    
    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        white-space: normal !important;   
    }
    
    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Event"; } /*used to be "Event"*/
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Time"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Standard"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "P/F/T"; }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Athlete"; }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Age at Meet"; }
    td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Swim Date"; }
    td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Meet Name"; }
}
```

Table Desktop Appearance

[image: Table Desktop Appearance]

Table Mobile Appearance

[image: Table Mobile Appearance]

Comment: ***There are many restrictions - no jquery, javascript. Just CSS and HTML. Even some CSS is not allowed.*** - What are you expecting?

Comment: And again, English is not my native language, but I have read your question now 3 times, and it is absolutely bad formulated and makes little sense. You could for example share which CMS is being used and add it as a tag for your question, so other users that use this specific CMS could more likely help you out.

Comment: Can you be more clear in what you want to achieve and only add the really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just a parent volunteer for this swim club. I am dismayed by the willingness of some users' to penalize someone instead of asking me to clarify my question.

The CMS is used by TeamUnify - their support staff don't even know what company created it. I don't think this would have helped anyone.

Anyone can see by my score that I am new user. It's a difficult thing when a person **doesn't even know the proper language** to use to ask a question - I did the best I could at the time.

I did find an apparently simple solution using pure CSS adapting information from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408688/how-do-i-select-columns-including-colspans-in-a-table) page. It took me a few days. I felt I should post this to close the question. Thanks to those whom offered positive feedback.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/john1968/opfnba62/)

```
    tr td[colspan="7"]::before {
    content: "Event";
    font-weight: bold;
      }

    td:nth-of-type(1)::before { content: "#"; }
```